# Navigo Javascript routing: Every route I register didn't match any of the registered routes

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

I'm learning how to make a single page app with javascript.

My javascript teacher provided a beautiful tutorial how to create a single page application from scratch. I followed the tutorial and everything went well untill the part where the routing came in..

He uses a library which is called navigo. I don't know why but it seems to not working for me at all.

The moment I've written the final line of code. My homepage disappeared and the console gave a warning that my route '/' which is my homepage, didn't match any of the registered routes, but it looks like there is no route registered at all, while I'm definitly registering them..

here is my code

My root index.js

```
import './sass/main.scss';
import App from './App';
import { HomeComponent, NewEventComponent } from './Components';

// Retrieve appComponent
const initApp = () => {
  const appContainer = document.getElementById('appContainer');

  const app = new App(appContainer);
  app.addComponent(new HomeComponent());
  app.addComponent(new NewEventComponent());
};

window.addEventListener('load', initApp);
```

My App.js (here is where my route is  defined for every component. routerPath makes it dynamic )

```
// The App Wrapper

import Component from './lib/Component';
import Router from './Router';

class App {
  constructor(parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.components = [];
  }

  clearparent() {
    while (this.parent.firstChild) {
      this.parent.removeChild(this.parent.lastChild);
    }
  }

  addComponent(component) {
    if (!(component instanceof Component)) return;

    // get the name from our component
    const { name, routerPath } = component;

    // when a component asks to reRender
    component.reRender = () => this.showComponent(component);

    // add to internal class
    this.components.push(component);

    // add to router
    Router.getRouter().on(routerPath, () => {
      this.showComponent({ name });
    }).resolve();
  }

  showComponent({ name }) {
    const foundComponent = this.components.find((component) => component.name === name);
    if (!foundComponent) return;
    this.clearparent();
    this.parent.appendChild(foundComponent.render());
  }
}

export default App;
```

The Home Component

```
// The Home Component

import Component from '../lib/Component';
import Elements from '../lib/Elements';

class HomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super({
      name: 'home',
      model: {
        counter: 0,
      },
      routerPath: '/',
    });
  }

  incrementCounter() {
    this.model.counter += 1;
  }

  render() {
    const { counter } = this.model;
    // create home container
    const homeContainer = document.createElement('div');

    // append header
    homeContainer.appendChild(
      Elements.createHeader({
        textContent: `Current value is: ${counter}`,
      }),
    );

    // append button
    homeContainer.appendChild(
      Elements.createButton({
        textContent: 'increase',
        onClick: () => { this.incrementCounter(); },
      }),
    );

    return homeContainer;
  }
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

A Component

```
// My components
class Component {
  constructor({
    name,
    model,
    routerPath,
  }) {
    this.name = name;
    this.model = this.proxyModel(model);
    this.routerPath = routerPath;
    this.reRender = null;
  }

  proxyModel(model) {
    return new Proxy(model, {
      set: (obj, prop, value) => {
        obj[prop] = value;
        if (this.reRender) this.reRender();
        return true;
      },
    });
  }
}

export default Component;
```

The Router

```
// My Router

import Navigo from 'navigo';

const Router = {
  router: null,
  getRouter() {
    if (!this.router) {
      const rootUrl = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}`;
      this.router = new Navigo(rootUrl, false);
    }
    return this.router;
  },
};

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I switched to Navigo(^7.0.0) and it works!

I seem to have the same problem as you. I'm also using navigo (^8.11.1). The problem is fixed for me when I declare a new router like this: new Navigo('/', false).
It still gives me the warning now, but it loads the page. sadly, this will only work in a dev environment